# When would flex class be more advantageous than the column and row classes?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

From the documentation about the [flex class:](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flex-class.html)

> The Flex widget allows you to control the axis along which the children are placed (horizontal or vertical). This is referred to as the main axis. If you know the main axis in advance, then consider using a Row (if it's horizontal) or Column (if it's vertical) instead, because that will be less verbose.

The documentation suggests that you wouldn't know which direction is the main axis (horizontal or vertical). How could you not know the main axis, and why would you want to change it? Would you only use flex in certain circumstances with a rotating screen? Or is this just an outdated class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not an outdated classes. When you use [`Row`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html) or [`Column`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html), you know the direction but you can use `Flex` and change the direction as you like(rotation or whatever, may be based on condition).

However, the [`Row`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html) and `Column` inherit from `Flex`. If you read the `Row` class doc, you will see something like this:

> Inheritance
>
> ```
>  Object -> Diagnosticable -> DiagnosticableTree -> Widget -> RenderObjectWidget  -> MultiChildRenderObjectWidget -> Flex -> Row
> ```

The [`Flexible`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html) widget also has a parent class called [`ParentDataWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ParentDataWidget-class.html) of type [`Flex`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flex-class.html).